# Can't svn2git public repos

Tags: git-svn, svn2git

I need to migrate a customer from SVN to Git, so I wanted first to try svn2git on a public SVN repository.

I have found several public repos, e.g., https://svn.alfresco.com/repos/alfresco-open-mirror/alfresco and http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/spamassassin. There is no problem of doing `svn co`, but when I try svn2git, I get the following problem:

`D:\Documents\work\svn2git\apache>svn2git http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/spamassassin
Initialized empty Git repository in D:/Documents/work/svn2git/apache/.git/
Using higher level of URL: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/spamassassin => http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf
W: Ignoring error from SVN, path probably does not exist: (160013): Filesystem has no item: REPORT request failed on '/repos/asf/!svn/bc/100': File not found: revision 100, path '/spamassassin'
W: Do not be alarmed at the above message git-svn is just searching aggressively for old history.
This may take a while on large repositories
Checked through r100
Checked through r200
Checked through r300`

It ran the whole night, and ended with:

`Checked through r22000
Checked through r22100
W: Ignoring error from SVN, path probably does not exist: (175002): RA layer request failed: PROPFIND request failed on '/repos/asf': PROPFIND of '/repos/asf': could not connect to server (http://svn.apache.org)
W: Do not be alarmed at the above message git-svn is just searching aggressively  for old history.
This may take a while on large repositories
Checked through r477700
Path 'spamassassin' was probably deleted:
RA layer request failed: PROPFIND request failed on '/repos/asf': PROPFIND of '/repos/asf': could not connect to server (http://svn.apache.org)
Will attempt to follow revisions r477601 .. r477700 committed before the deletion
r477601 .. r477679 OK
Checked through r748600
Path 'spamassassin' was probably deleted:
RA layer request failed: PROPFIND request failed on '/repos/asf': PROPFIND of '/repos/asf': could not connect to server (http://svn.apache.org)
Will attempt to follow revisions r748501 .. r748600 committed before the deletion
Checked through r748700
Checked through r748800
Checked through r748900
Checked through r749000
Checked through r749100
Checked through r749200
Checked through r749300
Checked through r749400
W: Ignoring error from SVN, path probably does not exist: (175002): RA layer request failed: PROPFIND request failed on '/repos/asf/!svn/vcc/default': PROPFIND of '/repos/asf/!svn/vcc/default': could not connect to server (http://svn.apache.org)
W: Do not be alarmed at the above message git-svn is just searching aggressively for old history.
This may take a while on large repositories
Checked through r805700
Path 'spamassassin' was probably deleted:
RA layer request failed: PROPFIND request failed on '/repos/asf/!svn/vcc/default': PROPFIND of '/repos/asf/!svn/vcc/default': could not connect to server (http://svn.apache.org)
Will attempt to follow revisions r805601 .. r805700 committed before the deletion
Checked through r805800
Checked through r805900
Checked through r806000
Checked through r806100
Checked through r806200
Checked through r806300
Checked through r806400
Checked through r806500
Checked through r806600
Checked through r806700
command failed:
git checkout -f master`

Why does it happen? Is it a permission problem?

Answer (score 0):

Well, so far everything looks fine. If it fails, you should specify with what message it fails.

But besides that, for a one-time migration `git-svn` (the `svn2git` tool you use is based on `git-svn`) is **not** the right tool for conversions of repositories or parts of repositories. It is a great tool if you want to use Git as frontend for an existing SVN server, but for one-time conversions you should **not** use `git-svn` or tools based on it, but `svn2git` which is much more suited for this use-case.

There are plenty tools called `svn2git`, the probably best one is the KDE one from https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git. I strongly recommend using that `svn2git` tool. It is the best I know available out there and it is very flexible in what you can do with its rules files. The `svn2git` that is based on `git-svn` suffers from most of the same drawbacks than pur `git-svn`, just working around of some of the issues.

You will be easily able to configure `svn2git`s rule file to produce the result you want from your current SVN layout, including any complex histories that might exist and including producing several Git repos out of one SVN repo or combining different SVN repos into one Git repo cleanly in one run if you like.

If you are not 100% about the history of your repository, `svneverever` from http://blog.hartwork.org/?p=763 is a great tool to investigate the history of an SVN repository when migrating it to Git.

---

Even though `git-svn` is easier to start with, here are some further reasons why using the KDE `svn2git` instead of `git-svn` is superior, besides its flexibility:

- the history is rebuilt much better and cleaner by `svn2git` (if the correct one is used), this is especially the case for more complex histories with branches and merges and so on
- the tags are real tags and not branches in Git
- with `git-svn` the tags contain an extra empty commit which also makes them not part of the branches, so a normal `fetch` will not get them until you give `--tags` to the command as by default only tags pointing to fetched branches are fetched also. With the proper svn2git tags are where they belong
- if you changed layout in SVN you can easily configure this with `svn2git`, with `git-svn` you will loose history eventually
- with `svn2git` you can also split one SVN repository into multiple Git repositories easily
- or combine multiple SVN repositories in the same SVN root into one Git repository easily
- the conversion is a gazillion times faster with the correct `svn2git` than with `git-svn`

You see, there are many reasons why `git-svn` is worse and the KDE `svn2git` is superior. :-)